# Failure to index in Elasticsearch an array

Tags: arrays, indexing, elasticsearch, xelement

I have an Elasticsearch index with the following mapping for "metadata" element:

```
metadata: {
  dynamic: true
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: string
    }
    data: {
      dynamic: true
      properties: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I create index entries by executing the following NEST call:

```
    var response = elasticClient.Index(item, x =>
        x.Index("testIndex").Type("clip").Id(itemId));
```

where "item" is an instance of XElement.

As long as "item" has only a single node "metadata" everything works fine, but if there are several "metadata" nodes I am getting the following error:

"object mapping for [clip_full] with array for [metadata] tried to parse as array, but got EOF, is there a mismatch in types for the same field?"

This is quite strange because AFAIK arrays don't need any mapping precaution: any mapped element can be sent in multiple instances. And if I pre-process the "item" XElement and remove all but one "metadata" nodes, indexing works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it seems related on how you create your data. I'm searching more info on it but it seems that the object pre parsing transforms single object array in object itself, corrupting your object schema.

EDIT: As usual, the problem comes from the one using the tool. My json generation was wrong, inserting different types in an array between 2 documents. I.e. some strings were created instead of object in arrays.